# Result vue.js to text input html

Tags: jquery, html, servlets, vue.js, qr-code

I'm using scan QR code from web camera. [instascan](https://github.com/schmich/instascan)

In `index.html` call function `app.js(instascan/docs/..)` But I can't use result value in tag `{{scan.content}}` to tag input type text for send to `java servlet`.

```
<transition-group name="scans" tag="ul">
<ul id="resultQR" v-for="scan in scans" :key="scan.date" :title="scan.content">
  {{ scan.content }}
</ul>
```

I'm must to

`<input type="text" name="qrcode" value="{{ scan.content }}">`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `:key` binding. You don't have matching key binding.

Change this:

```
v-for="scan in scans" :key="scan.date"
```

With this:

```
v-for="(scan,key) in scans" :key="key"
```

Now, everything will work fine.